# any way to run passenger-status --show=requests without being root?

Tags: ruby, phusion-passenger

Periodically in production we get these ruby processes that hang up.  I just discovered

```
passenger-status  --show=requests
```

Which gives me exactly what I want.  I want to write some code to build out a super admin panel that will let me click on processes and see what the request is, however, when I run this command I get

```
ERROR: You are not authorized to query the status for this Phusion Passenger instance. Please try again with 'sudo'
```

Is there a way to authorize my user (deploy) to run this, rather than force sudo?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently passenger's [admin API is over UNIX sockets](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1407#issuecomment-77680784). You would need to become a user who can access that socket file.

root obviously can do it. Maybe you can change the socket to be readable by your user. Regarding security, the [documented example requests JSON](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/overall_status_report.html#viewing-active-requests)  does not appear to have sensitive data, (although you should evaluate this yourself).